# Why does Eclipse CDT generate a binary file when I make a .out extension file (instead of making a regular text file)

Tags: eclipse, file, binary, eclipse-cdt

When programming in Eclipse CDT (neon), I have noticed that every time I make a file that is with the extension.out it automatically changes to a binary file. I'm not able to change that. Does anyone know how to fix this/why this is?

Image with the package explorer containing a regular txt file and a binary file:

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that traditionally `.out` has been the extension for executable files (["a.out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) is file format and ["a.out"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) is the default executable name for gcc if no `-o` is given.)

If you do not use `.out` as your file extension of choice for binary files, right-click on the file, choose *Open With* -> *Other*, choose your preferred editor and check *Use it for all '*.out' files" if desired:

[image: editor selection]

You can also edit/update file types in *Preferences* -> *General* -> *Editors* -> *File Associations*:

[image: File Associations Preferences]